# Adding two random numbers together

Tags: python, random, addition

So im having trouble adding 2 randomly generated numbers together. the user has to see the two random numbers generated and then the computer has to add them together and print that out. can anyone show me what im doing wrong?

```
import random
import time

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    min = 1
    max = 6
    print("Rolling the dices...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("The values are...")
    time.sleep(2)
    dice1 = print(random.randint(min, max))
    dice2 = print(random.randint(min, max))

    usertotal = dice1 + dice2
```

Comment: `print(random.randint(min, max))` => `random.randint(min, max)` or you'll get `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are printing to the terminal the random numbers, you don't store them in the variables dice1 and dice2. Your code won't work.

```
dice1 = print(random.randint(min, max))
dice2 = print(random.randint(min, max))
usertotal = dice1 + dice2
```

Instead you should do this:

```
dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
print(dice1)
dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
print(dice2)
usertotal = dice1 + dice2
print(usertotal)
```